# Cannot delete the column in DataFrame Pandas by del function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the function `del df['column name']` to delete the column in Pandas but there is the error as the attached picture. I have no idea why it does not work. Much appreciated for any help to solve the problem.   [image]

Comment: It says your `baby_names` DataFrame has no column `'Year'`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop) method instead.

```
df.drop(columns='column_name')
```

And if you want to chage the original Dataframe you should add the `inplace=True` as an argument to the method.

Also, avoid posting pictures if possible. Posting the written code is often more usufel and makes it easier for someone to help you!

Comment: While this is useful information and definitely the right way to delete a column, have you verified that this works when the `del` method throws a `KeyError` in pandas to be sure it actually answers the question? If not, this would be better as a comment. See also: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)